# Append duplicate key value pair to nested dictionary in YAML

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to append duplicate key: value pair to a nested dictionary in a YAML file through python script. Following is the snippet of the code which I have written to achieve this:

```
import click
import ruamel.yaml

def organization():
    org_num = int(input("Please enter the number of organizations to be created: "))
    org_val = 0
    while org_val!= org_num:
        print ("")
        print("Please enter values to create Organizations")
        print ("")
        for org in range(org_num):
            organization.org_name = str(raw_input("Enter the Organization Name: "))
            organization.org_description = str(raw_input("Enter the Description of Organization: "))
            print ("")
            if click.confirm("Organization Name: "+ organization.org_name + "\nDescription: "+ organization.org_description + "\nIs this Correct?", default=True):
                if org_val == 0:
                    org_val = org_val + 1
                    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
                    org_data = dict(
                        organizations=dict(
                            name=organization.org_name,
                            description=organization.org_description,
                        )
                    )
                    with open('input.yml', 'a') as outfile:
                        yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
                        yaml.dump(org_data, outfile)

               else:
                   org_val = org_val + 1
                   yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
                   org_data = dict(
                            name=organization.org_name,
                            description=organization.org_description,
                            )
                   with open('input.yml', 'r') as yamlfile:
                       cur_yaml = yaml.load(yamlfile)
                       cur_yaml['organizations'].update(org_data)

                   if cur_yaml:
                       with open('input.yml','w') as yamlfile:
                           yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
                           yaml.dump(cur_yaml, yamlfile)
    return organization.org_name, organization.org_description

organization()
```

At the end of python script my `input.yml` file should look like the following:

```
version: x.x.x
is_enterprise: 'true'
license: secrets/license.txt
organizations:
  -  description: xyz
     name: abc
  -  description: pqr
     name: def
```

However every time the script is running, instead of appending the value to organizations it overwrites it.

I also have tried using append instead of update but I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'CommentedMap' object has no attribute 'append'

What can I do to solve this?

Also since I am new to development, any suggestion on making this code better will be really helpful.

Comment: Which yaml library are you using?

Comment: Added the same in the post. Sorry i am new to stackoverflow. Please let me know in case you need some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue and its working fine now. Since name and description are list objects for organizations, I have added []  to the below code and it started working.

```
org_data = dict(
    organizations=[dict(
        name=tower_organization.org_name,
        description=tower_organization.org_description,
    )
    ]
)
```

In addition to above, I guess append wasn't working because of the hyphen '-' which was missing from the first object as part of the identation. After fixing the above code, append is working fine as well.

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is `cur_yaml['organizations'] += [org_data]`.

Note that if you run the script many times, you will have the same entry multiple times.

Comment: I have tried adding append instead of update but i get below error :-

AttributeError: 'CommentedMap' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Can you edit your original post with that trial and error so that we can see?

Comment: I updated the answer with the new context `from ruamel.yaml import YAML`

Comment: Tried it with the above changes. Now i am getting below error :- 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'CommentedMap' and 'list'

Answer (score 0):

Using `update` is not going to work, because the value for for the key
`organizations` is a sequence and loads as the `list`-like type
`CommentedSeq`. So `append`-ing would be the right thing to do.

That that doesn't work is a bit unclear since you don't provide that input
that you start with, nor the code used when doing the `append`ing which gets
an `AttributeError` on `CommentedMap`.

Here is what works if you have one organization and add another:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
version: x.x.x
is_enterprise: 'true'
license: secrets/license.txt
organizations:
  -  description: xyz
     name: abc
"""

org_data = dict(
   description='pqr',
   name='def',
)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)

cur_yaml = yaml.load(yaml_str)
cur_yaml['organizations'].append(org_data)
yaml.dump(cur_yaml, sys.stdout)
```

This gives:

```
version: x.x.x
is_enterprise: 'true'
license: secrets/license.txt
organizations:
  - description: xyz
    name: abc
  - description: pqr
    name: def
```

If you have no organizations yet, make sure your input YAML looks like:

```
version: x.x.x
is_enterprise: 'true'
license: secrets/license.txt
organizations: []
```

On older versions of Python the order of the keys in the data you added is not guaranteed. To
enforce that order on older version as well do:

```
org_data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap((('description', 'pqr'), ('name', 'def')))
```

or

```
org_data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
org_data['description'] = 'pqr'
org_data['name'] = 'def'
```

Comment: I have updated the post with the code being used. Tried adding extend and got the below error:

AttributeError: 'CommentedMap' object has no attribute 'extend'